# Array sendo reescrevido completamente dentro do foreach

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, ecmascript-6, firestore

Estou realizando um sistema de votação pelo firestore, e estou com um problema em relação ao comportamento de um array dentro do foreach, segue o código:

```
         busca_votos:  function(pergunta){
            let path  =  firebase.firestore().collection('database').doc(this.id_cliente).collection('assembleia')
            let temas = []
            let valor_voto = []

            path
                .doc(this.id_assembleia)
                .collection('votos')
                .where('id_voto', '==', pergunta)
                .get().then( snapshot =>{
                    snapshot.docs.forEach( dado =>{
                        temas.push(dado.data().id_tema)
                        valor_voto.push(pergunta)
                })

            })
            console.log(valor_voto)
        },
```

A função acima recebe o parâmetro 'pergunta', e nele vem um id da pergunta que está no firestore, o que eu faço na query da função é comparar se na collection 'votos' existe esse id (se existir quer dizer que houveram votos).
O meu problema está no "valor_voto.push(pergunta)". Eu gostaria que ele fizesse um push nesse array toda vez que encontrar um valor, mas o que acontece é que ele "sobrescreve" o array todo, o meu resultado fica algo parecido com:

```
>[]
  0: "77784"
  1: "77784"
  length: 2

>[]
  length: 0

>[]
  0: "124520"
  length: 1
```

OBS: Os números que são printados no array são os id's das perguntas.

Alguem sabe o por quê desse comportamento? Gostaria que ele me devolvesse um array só com todos os id's votados para poder fazer a contagem de vezes que ele aparece ...

Answer (score 2):

Olá!

Na verdade eu creio que o teu código esteja executando "corretamente", porém o que esta causando este comportamento no seu `console.log()` é chamar ele depois do `.get()` que é assíncrono pois retorna uma `Promise()`. Pra testar você pode colocar o `console.log()` depois do `forEach()`, porém você não vai conseguir retornar a variável `valor_votos` fora do `.then()`.

Uma maneira de resolver isso seria utilizando async/await:

```
async function getVotos() {
  const votos = [];

  const querySnapshot = await firestore()
    .collection('votos')
    .get();

  querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
    votos.push(documentSnapshot.data());
  });

  console.log(votos);

  return votos;
};
```

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: Em partes ajudou sim, com o async eu fico menos preocupado com o fato dele seguir o comportamento normal do JS. Contúdo a impressão que eu tenho é que ele ainda esta reescrevendo por algum motivo, segue o don't pad: https://dontpad.herokuapp.com/javascript